# Pyqt5: Pass a value dynamically in QlineEdit box when event is clicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt5

In need a pass a result from an event to **QlineEdit** box(**rs_QLineEdit**)
If the event is clicked by passing the Book name it displays book name and price.
There is no problem with database connection as it works well and displays the result in python shell.

I want to pass the price dynamically which is to pass **m[2]** to **rs_QLineEdit**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRegExp
from PyQt5.QtGui import QRegExpValidator
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlite3

def fetch(nm):
    store=sqlite3.connect("store.db")
    book=store.cursor()
    book.execute("select * from books where title='"+nm+"';")
    m=book.fetchone()
    if m==None:
        print("Book is not Found")
    else:
        print("the name is {} ".format(nm))  #The Wings of Fire
        print(m[2])                          #200

    store.close()

class Ui_Form(object):
def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName("Form")
    Form.resize(635, 510)
    self.find = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
    self.find.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 200, 93, 28))
    self.find.setObjectName("find_button")
    self.find.setToolTip("Press this")
    self.name = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
    self.name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 200, 55, 16))
    self.name.setObjectName("name_label")
    self.price = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
    self.price.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 260, 55, 16))
    self.price.setObjectName("price_label")
    self.rs = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
    self.rs.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 260, 55, 16))
    self.rs.setObjectName("rs_QLineEdit")
    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 200, 113, 22))
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")


    self.retranslateUi(Form)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    self.find.clicked.connect(lambda : fetch(str(self.lineEdit.text())))

    reg_ex = QRegExp("[0-9]+.?[0-9]{,2}")
    input_validator = QRegExpValidator(reg_ex, self.rs)
    self.rs.setValidator(input_validator)

def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
    self.find.setText(_translate("Form", "Find"))
    self.name.setText(_translate("Form", "Name"))
    self.price.setText(_translate("Form", "Price"))
    self.rs.setText(_translate("Form", "RS."))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although lambda methods are useful for certain types of tasks in general you should not abuse them because they have many limitations, in your case the fetch function should return the result but within a lambda method it is difficult to establish (it can be in theory but it would be unreadable).

In addition to this I take the trouble to improve your code following the recommendations of PyQt: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code, in it I recommend not to modify the class generated by Qt Designer but to implement another class that inherits from the widget and use the initial class to fill in the widget, in that new class the logic is implemented.

Code:

```
import sqlite3

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


def fetch(nm):
    store=sqlite3.connect("store.db")
    book=store.cursor()
    book.execute("select * from books where title='{}';".format(nm))
    m=book.fetchone()
    store.close()
    if m:
        print("the name is {} ".format(nm))
        return m[2] 
    else:
        print("Book is not Found")

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(635, 510)
        self.find = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.find.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 200, 93, 28))
        self.find.setObjectName("find_button")
        self.find.setToolTip("Press this")
        self.name = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 200, 55, 16))
        self.name.setObjectName("name_label")
        self.price = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.price.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 260, 55, 16))
        self.price.setObjectName("price_label")
        self.rs = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.rs.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 260, 55, 16))
        self.rs.setObjectName("rs_QLineEdit")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 200, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.find.setText(_translate("Form", "Find"))
        self.name.setText(_translate("Form", "Name"))
        self.price.setText(_translate("Form", "Price"))
        self.rs.setText(_translate("Form", "RS."))

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.find.clicked.connect(self.onFindClicked)

        reg_ex = QtCore.QRegExp("[0-9]+.?[0-9]{,2}")
        input_validator = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(reg_ex, self.rs)
        self.rs.setValidator(input_validator)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onFindClicked(self):
        title = self.lineEdit.text()
        name = fetch(title)
        if name:
            self.rs.setText(str(name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Although the function is working but it can't pass the value to rs_QLineEdit box

Comment: @KrishnaKishore `rs_QLineEdit`' is the `self.rs`, in my code I clearly do it with `self.rs.setText(name)`

Comment: @KrishnaKishore 
if you realize, I have modified the fetch function.

Comment: @KrishnaKishore Do not share code in the comments if it is large, instead indicate me that it is printed in the terminal and as I emphasize do not modify my code.

Comment: File "C:\New folder\try.py", line 65, in onFindClicked
    self.rs.setText(name)
TypeError: setText(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'

Comment: @KrishnaKishore clearly `m[2]` is a number integer and that you did not mention it in your question, I have updated my code, try it back please. :)

Comment: @KrishnaKishore 
I know, just to mark my answer as correct is enough, when you have more reputation you give me the upvote. :)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is fine, but I don't necessarily agree about avoiding lambda functions. They are super useful when programming in PyQt. As per [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) for `QPushButton`'s super class `QAbstractButton`, `clicked` takes one argument, `bool checked = false`. It's actually pretty useless on QPushButton as far as I've seen, but nevertheless, your lambda has to account for any arguments. Change your connect line to

```
self.find.clicked.connect(lambda c: fetch(str(self.lineEdit.text())))
                               # ^ This is the important part
```